# How is the Eclipse JDK setting affecting the system's JDK setting

Tags: eclipse, macos, grails, java

I was trying to compile a Grails application referencing third party JARs on Mac OSX. Although my system's JRE and JDK is set to Java 1.6 I always got a `Compilation error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file`
when accessing classes in the JAR. Also when testing an existing Grails app the default stats of the app where showing that it's running with Java 1.6. So I really didn't have more ideas than to try to change the Java settings in Eclipse - I thought that's stupid as I'm not using Eclipse for the devlopment of this application - but voila - now the compilation of my app on the command line works just fine!

Can anyone explain me what Eclipse is doing here behind the scenes?
I've had set the JAVA_HOME manually before with no effect.

Comment: > I just changed the default JRE in Exclipe: if you are referring to the declared "installed JRE" that should not have any side-effect (except recompiling existing projects referenced in Eclipse... but you said you have none? So why Eclipse was opened in the first place?)

Comment: Opening Eclipse (and further development in Eclipse) was the last idea I had as the env vars are handled differently in eclipse - but I didn't even come to the point to compile it in Eclipse - I just changed the default JRE setting in Eclipse to 1.6 (the command line JAVA_HOME was already 1.6 before) and then tried (without much hope) to compile it on the command line again - and it worked. I can't explain myself.

Answer (score 4):

The JDK (JAVA_HOME) used to launched eclipse is not necessarily the one used to compiled your project.

To see what JRE YOU y can select for your project, check the preferences

```
General > Java Installed JRE
```

By default, if you have not added any JRE, the only one declared will be the one used to launched eclipse (which can be defined in your [**`eclipse.ini`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)).
You can add any other JRE you want, including one compatible with your project.

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/images/task-add_jre_std_vm.PNG]

After that, you will need to check in your project properties (or in the general preferences) what JRE is used, with what compliance level:

[image: http://www.standartux.fr/public/Java/Preferences.png]

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply but I was not using Eclipse for that specific project before - Command Line and TextMate only! Here the compilation did not work because of an "Bad Version" error as I would run a Java 6 project with Java 5. But I didn't - everything looked like Java 6. But then I did the same what you have mentioned - I just changed the default JRE in Exclipse but did NOT import the project to eclipse and did NOT compile it using eclipse. I was still compiling from the command line with "grails compile" - and now the compilation suddendly succeeded without any errors. Sounds strange.