# configuring m2eclipse: "Eclipse is running in a JRE but a JDK is required"

Tags: eclipse, java, m2eclipse

After installed m2eclipse, I received a message saying that Eclipse needs to "run in a JDK" and to update the eclipse.ini to do so.

So I added this:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
```

as the last two lines of the eclipse.ini file in my Eclipse installation directory.

However, I am again receiving this warning.

Did I not enter the command correctly?

Comment: You might find a hint here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317402/eclipse-maven-plugin-configuration-problem/3317501#3317501 The newline in eclipse.ini might cause problems and that would result in Eclipse using a different VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The value must be the full absolute
>   path to the Java executable, not just
>   to the Java home directory.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe
```

should work. source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

It can be path to JDK if you're using command line. I usually create a shortcut to eclipse with extra parameter: -vm "path_to_jdk", it'll using jvm.dll(jvm.so) instead of java.exe,javaw.exe, so you won't see external process name java.exe in your process list.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, the solution to this problem has nothing to do with slashes, backslashes, quotes, spaces, jre, jdk, jvm, javaw, ....

The answer is that you have to have a line break between

-vm

and the path.

So in the eclipse.ini file:

```
THIS WILL NOT WORK:
-vm C:\java\jdk\bin\javaw.exe

BUT THIS WILL:
-vm
C:\java\jdk\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the suggestions in this thread, the only thing I could to work with Eclipse Indigo was using a shortcut with the -vm switch on the end like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Indigo 3.7M6\eclipse.exe" -vm C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\
```