# Maven in Eclipse complains that "Unable to locate the Javac Compiler" whenever POM changed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I got error message every time  I changed my pom.xml in eclipse.

```
Build errors for myapp; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project web: Compilation failure
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable
```

I have set JAVA_HOME environment variable. It is:JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue and i am not able to slove by this answer can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049566/an-internal-error-occurred-during-enabling-maven-dependency-management-unsup

Answer (score 54):

This is the step I did to solve that problem (Eclipse 3.7 Indigo):

**Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs** -> I have a JRE from the JDK location, my location looks like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`

**Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> Execution Environments** -> Select JavaSE-1.6 and select a compatible JDK which should be the one set in the previous step.

Comment: I had to add a new "Standard VM" entry in the UI, and specify my JAVA_HOME folder to the JDK for that entry, then I was able to select the check box for the item I had added, as described.

Comment: If this does not work, doublecheck that the project itself is configured to use the JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> Execution Environments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 19):

None of the above worked for me but when I followed the following steps, the problem went away.

- Go to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **installed JREs**
- Select the JRE you are using (Should be the one inside jdk. Ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre)
- Press **Edit** -> **Add External JARs...**
- Browse to **Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib** and select **tools.jar** and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press **Finish** and **OK**

Comment: I have the same issue and i am not able to slove by this answer can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049566/an-internal-error-occurred-during-enabling-maven-dependency-management-unsup

Answer (score 4):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> Execution Enviroments -> click the checkbox on the right side

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue which I just figured out.  The Runtime JRE was specified correctly in EVERY other part of eclipse.

I use an eclipse Run Configuration...

The *Run Configuration* is YET ANOTHER place where the java runtime JRE is specified.
If you are using a maven Run Configuration, open that up, click the JRE tab and select the proper (JDK) "Runtime JRE".

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me too :

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Select the JRE you are using (Should be the one inside jdk. Ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre)
3. Press Edit -> Add External JARs...
4. Browse to Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib and select tools.jar and Press Enter
5. Press Finish and OK

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following **two** lines at the very beginning of your eclipse.ini file should tell maven where to find JDK:

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe

or whatever path you installed JDK into.

Comment: The command should be  ------------      

set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

Comment: I have the same issue and i am not able to slove by this answer can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049566/an-internal-error-occurred-during-enabling-maven-dependency-management-unsup

Answer (score 1):

If you are encountering this problem when trying to run maven from eclipse, then you may want to refer to [this discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-locate-the-Javac-Compiler-Problem-td133804.html), which also outlines the solution.

Comment: It seems working,but I still got some error:Build errors for myapp; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project web: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:

Comment: my last comment is stacktrace.

Comment: I have the same issue and i am not able to slove by this answer can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049566/an-internal-error-occurred-during-enabling-maven-dependency-management-unsup

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; what you should try is performing a **mvn install** from the POM directory itself, any Maven install you do next in Eclipse itself will work as well afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar issue it got resolved by specifying attributes of the maven-compiler-plugin as below:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
<!-- Need to provide the below properties as the current maven-compiler-plugin version is 2.0.2 and defaults to JDK 1.3 for compiling -->
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I had to explicitly specify the source and target attribute. it seems there compilation also depends on the version maven-compiler-plugin and its default JDK setting. Mine was 2.0.2 and its default was JDK 1.3 i gather.

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2.Select the JRE you are using (Should be the one inside jdk. Ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre)
3.Press Edit -> Add External JARs...
4.Browse to Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib and select tools.jar and Press Enter
5.Press Finish and OK..

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JAVA_HOME is not set properly. Can you echo JAVA_HOME from your terminal & see where it is pointing to? From the above error log it looks like its pointing to program files folder.

Comment: D:\Users\tom>set java_home
JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23        And I have that folder.

Comment: The command should be  ------------      

set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

Comment: No, my command is：set JAVA_HOME, and the result is:JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs, add jdk6 to point to your jdk(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25), delete default jre6. it works.