# Maven2: Missing artifact but jars are in place

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

From now to then, my Maven 2 started to mess around.

I am using SPring STS 2.6.1 and have a single project based on Spring 3, Hibernate, DWR, Cometd and all that stuff.

Today I just updated from Git und all of a sudden, I got that scary `mvn` exclamation mark (!) next to my project.

After hitting "Project -> Maven -> Update dependencies" I just receive:

```
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-common:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-analyzers:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-highlighter:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-queries:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-snowball:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-spellchecker:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.solr:solr-commons-csv:jar:1.3.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20040917:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-snowball:jar:2.4.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:2.4.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-parent:pom:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:system
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:pom:1.0.2.GA:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.10:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.0-801.jdbc4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:2.0.3:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.7:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8-beta1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.5.3:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.7:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact eclipse:jdtcore:jar:3.1.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.0:test
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:test
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:pom:2.3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:jar:2.3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.opensymphony.quartz:quartz-all:jar:1.6.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.5:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.0.7:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.cometd.java:cometd-java-server:jar:1.0.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.cometd.java:cometd-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.0.1.v20091125:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.0.1.v20091125:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.htmlparser.jericho:jericho-html:jar:3.1:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-core:jar:1.3.3:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact redis.clients:jedis:jar:1.5.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.5.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:jar:R8pre2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:jar:0.97-incubator:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact com.kenai.nbpwr:com-sun-pdfview:jar:1.0.5-201003191900:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.swinglabs:pdf-renderer:jar:1.0.5:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:2.0.0:system
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact de.dankomannhaupt:JDBCAppender:jar:1.0:system
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact spy:memcahed:jar:2.5:system
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.sf.beanlib:beanlib:jar:5.0.2beta:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact xstream:xstream:jar:1.1.2:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
24.05.11 15:26:58 MESZ: Missing artifact net.sf.beanlib:beanlib-hibernate:jar:5.0.2beta:compile
```

My `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.3.2.GA</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <name>JBoss Repsitory</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!-- Bezeichnung -->
    <artifactId>project-dao</artifactId>
    <name>Vevention Dao</name>
    <groupId>com.corp.dao</groupId>
    <version>1.0Beta</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>system</scope> 
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar</systemPath> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>         

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-snowball</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1B</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>memcached</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>voldemort</groupId>
            <artifactId>voldemort</artifactId>
            <version>0.81</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I then checked on my Mac `/Users/XYZ/.m2` and all jar files are in place as expected.

I am using the current Maven release shipped with STS. I also enabled debug output but there was nothing suspicious.

Comment: this can be the answer of your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17663859/3343174

Answer (score 216, accepted):

There are a few other options apart from **Project**->**Clean**, some of which are more along the lines of turning it off and on again.

- Try right-clicking on the project and selecting **Maven**->**Update Project Configuration**.
- Disable then re-enable dependency management (right-click **Maven**->**Disable Dependency Management** then **Maven**->**Enable Dependency Management**
- Close the project and reopen it.
- Check that your Maven settings are configured correctly. If you are behind a proxy you'll need to [configure the proxy settings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) in the global or user settings.
- Check you're using the Maven installation you expect. By default m2eclipse uses the embedder, if you have a separate installation you may want to [configure m2eclipse](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/preferences.html#preferences-sect-maven-preferences) to use the external installation so that CLI and Eclipse builds are consistent. This also ensures you're configured to connect through any proxy as above.

Comment: as @cracked_all said below, when using Update Project Configuration, force it: Force Update of Snapshot/Releases

Comment: and restart Eclipse, as sad as it sounds, it sometimes fix.

Answer (score 64):

I received this same issue on SpringSource Tools ver 2.8.0.RELEASE. I had to do Maven -> Update Maven Dependencies and check the option for "Force Update of Snapshot/Releases".

Answer (score 55):

I encountered similar issue. The missing artifacts (jar files) exists in ~/.m2 directory and somehow eclipse is unable to find it.

For example:
Missing artifact org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile

I looked through this directory ~/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1 and I noticed there is this file _maven.repositories. I opened it using text editor and saw the following entry:

```
#NOTE: This is an internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Wed Feb 13 17:12:29 SGT 2013
jdom-1.1.jar>central=
jdom-1.1.pom>central=
```

I simply removed the "central" word from the file:

```
#NOTE: This is an internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Wed Feb 13 17:12:29 SGT 2013
jdom-1.1.jar>=
jdom-1.1.pom>=
```

and run Maven > Update Project from eclipse and it just worked :)
Note that your file may contain other keyword instead of "central".

Comment: This one just worked for me. None of the other solutions mentioned worked. I really wish something would displace Maven. This tool gives me so many problems, and when it fails, the error messages are useless. Thanks for the solution, though. I've just wasted about an hour trying to get this resolved, but this suggestion finally worked for me.

Comment: Worked for us but why was it an issue in the first place?  seems like a bug to me.  The artifacts are there why not see them?

Comment: same issue my case was _remote.repositories
    unbescape-1.0.pom>boss=
    unbescape-1.0.jar>boss=    just removed the boss words and worked like a charm

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm trying to resolve it by following your answer howerver, I do not have the name of the artifact, when i go through the repository, I end up in a folder with 2 files, one  named as the artifact and jar, the other with the artifacts name and pom. When I open one of them this is what I see : http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=

Comment: Yep, this is what helped me too with
Missing artifact com.splunk:splunk:jar:1.5.0.0

Used to be like this
splunk-1.5.0.0.jar>spring-milestones=
now its like this
splunk-1.5.0.0.jar>=

And no more errors

Comment: How did you find this solution? It did work for me too but what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem. Rich Seller's solution didn't work for my situation, I fixed it by cancel the `Window -> Preferences -> Maven`. `Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories` option, then right-clicking on the project and selecting `Maven->Update Project`.

Comment: YES!  This worked for me.  The issue is for my user it was trying to load from a non-existent repository, so annoying!

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same error with Spring Boot dependencies. What solved for me was letting Maven resolve the dependencies wrapping them with dependency management:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>...</dependency>
      ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I was getting this error for spring-boot-starter-log4j. I tried this suggestion and it removed the error from pom.xml. However, I was not able to use Logger in my java classes.

Comment: I think this is the good answer, but I would only move the ejb3-persistence dependency, as it is of type pom

Answer (score 14):

I had similar problem. it was showing error "Missing artifact......".After digging in, I found that I have proxy settings enabled which should be configured (proxyname, user/pwd) in setting.xml inside conf folder of Maven. As a resolution go to
Eclipse....`Windows->preferences->Maven->UserSettings`....and update the user setting to point the setting.xml which you have inside conf folder of Maven. After that go to `Project->Update All Maven Dependencies`. It should work fine after the build.

Comment: +1 I was using external maven setup (behind corporate proxy) and updating the user settings in STS with the settings.xml of this external installation, fixed all my project errors.

Comment: This was a problem I had.  I can't believe it doesn't use the conf directory under the Maven installation you have selected...

Answer (score 7):

Wow, this had me tearing my hair out, banging my head against walls, tables and other things.
I had the same or a similar issue as the OP where it was either missing / not downloading the jar files or downloading them, but not including them in the Maven dependencies with the same error message.
My limited knowledge of java packaging and maven probably didn't help.

For me the problem seems to have been caused by the *Dependency Type "bundle"*  (but I don't know how or why). I was using the Add Dependency dialog in Eclipse Mars on the pom.xml, which allows you to search and browse the central repository. I was searching and adding a dependency to jackson-core libraries, picking the latest version, available as a ***bundle***. This kept failing.

So finally, I changed the dependency properties form bundle to ***jar*** (again using the dependency properties window), which finally downloaded and referenced the dependencies properly after saving the changes.

Comment: Same thing just occured for me, with Eclipse Oxygen. Except that the dependency added via Add Dependency dialog was actually downloaded, but still was marked as "missing". I removed `<type>bundle</type>` manually from pom.xml at all, and after updating project it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, it turned out to be a missing artifact of solr that seemed to block all the rest of my build cycle.

I have no idea why mvn behaves like that, but upgrading to the latest version fixed it.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Which missing Solr artifact?  I'm getting the same error, and it's complaining about Solr dependencies (```Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:4.2.0 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1```).

Answer (score 3):

M2Eclipse sometimes does that. Select `Project > Clean ...` from the Menu and everything will be fine after the rebuild

Comment: I'm afraid but the red exclamation mark persists :( Already tried that several times...

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem. Just after adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

caused the problem. I deleted that dependency even then I'm getting the same error. I don't know what happened. I tried updating the maven dependency configuration which solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

After not much success with any of the answers available here so far.

**My solution:**

I downloaded the jar file manually and then installed the dependency by using Apache Maven `install:install-file` plugin, [see more details here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)

**A Full Example:**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
     <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Download jar file from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.4)
2. Install it by using the following command:

`mvn -X install:install-file " -DgroupId=commons-net" "-DartifactId=commons-net" "-Dversion=3.4" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dfile={your_full_downloads_path}/commons-net-3.4.jar"`

3. Click on the project and select `Maven->Update Project`

Answer (score 2):

i download the missing jar and placed in the .m2 repository fixed the problem =]

Comment: This works for me but I worry that it is going to cause issues for the next person who tries to build the project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, maven was complaining about a missing artifact, even though it existed in .m2/repository/[...]. In my case the problem was that I forgot to specify the correct repository in the pom.xml from which the package was downloaded originally (download by another project).

Adding the package repository to the pom.xml solved the problem.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>SomeName</id>
    <name>SomeName</name>
    <url>http://url.to.repo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks [Maximilianus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578559/maximilianus) for the hint to those "*.repositories" files in the package directory.

Answer (score 2):

Ohh what a mess! My advise: When its comes to messy poms or project packaging, Eclipse is really bad at showing the real problem. It will tell you some dependencies are missing, when in fact for pom is malformed or some other problem are present in your pom.

Leave Eclipse alone are run a maven install. You will get to the real problem really quick!

Comment: Yeah this worked for me, thanks. My problem was unauthorised access to a maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

As i tried all above as my friends said but nothing worked actually, I was facing same problem and found solution in some different way my issue starts when i added below repository

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>20040902.021138</version>
</dependency>
```

and my problem starts...so then i changed the version and took previous version and it removed all error. So i think this issue can because of the version we are adding in POM.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me.
1) Cut all the contents from pom.xml file and keep it another file and save the pom.xml 
2) Just delete .m2 folder(entire maven repository) and restart the eclipse(or jbdevstudio) 
3) paste the previous pom.xml file content(from the cut file) and all the error are gone.

Comment: I deleted the relevant folder inside of .m2 folder. This solved my problem - no other steps were requried.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and below step removed all these errors :

- Right click Project -> Maven -> Update Project

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code in pom.xml to download the jar

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

But in the .m2 folder under validation folder...the jar didnt get downloaded. I am not sure about the issue. But i downloaded the same jar from maven official website and placed in the .m2 folder under respective folder and cleaned the project. The error gone and it started working now.

Answer (score 1):

My case its version was missing and I found by searching that package in maven central with the version of "spring-boot-starter-parent"

Before change:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

After Change:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Just changed added version of the parent to the missing dependency

Answer (score 0):

My case following procedure solve the issue

1- [image]

2- check the active profile
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem a couple of times. The following solution worked for me.

1. copy the existing pom file as a back up, and delete the dependency that's causing this error. delete the contents of the folder which this artifact is referring to.
2. add the deleted dependency in the pom again and add the jar files in that folder.
3. do a Maven->update Project. The errors will go away.

As a side note, sometimes when you're copying files from some other computer there may be encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar solution like @maximilianus. The difference was that my .repositories files were called _remote.repositores and I had to delete them to make it work.

For eg in my case I deleted

- C:\Users\USERNAME.m2\repository\jta\jta\1.0.1_remote.repositories and
- C:\Users\USERNAME.m2\repository\jndi\jndi\1.2.1_remote.repositories

After doing so my errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar problem with SBT and slf4j. Nothing had changed, but on one machine it suddenly wouldn't build.

I tried:

- sbt clean
- deleting `target/`
- deleting project working directory and doing a fresh checkout/build
- deleting the `~/.sbt/<scala-version>/` folder
- deleting the offending slf4j folder from the `~/.ivy2` cache
- placing the missing slf4j jars in the expected ivy2 folder

None of the above worked.

So, I had to bite the bullet and delete my entire `~/.ivy2/` cache folder and wait for 2GB of dependencies to be downloaded again. I'm not familiar with what sort of cache manifests get written in there, but this must have been a corruption of one of them.

(using SBT 2.10.4 for Spark builds)

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions didn't work and you know the correct jars are in your repository then:

The problem is that eclipse caches the errors for some reason.

I solved this problem by deleting the errors in the Problems tab and then I refreshed the project explorer and all the exclamation points and errors never returned.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a bug that manifested as "Error installing artifact: File ../null/... does not exist" (that is, the file was not found because there was "null" in the path). The reason was that one environment variable was not visible to maven. It was:

```
JV_SRCROOT=$DIRECTORY
```

instead of

```
export JV_SRCROOT=$DIRECTORY
```

(in the latter case the variable is visible to child processes)

Answer (score 0):

After running eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse its worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to provide one more possible solution: In my case, I removed "central" from .m2/jdom/jdom/1.0 settings, and did everything else, without results.

So I discovered my settings.xml in ./m2 folder was stuck by a failed process. As I didn't found the process in the system task manager, I restarted the computer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works which was the case for me, in the problems view, right click and copy the errors and paste it in a text editor. And scroll down to see if there are other errors besides just the missing artifact.

Eclipse problems view only shows about 100 errors and the errors that are not visible might be the ones that's causing all the other missing artifact errors.

Once I saw all the errors, I was able to figure out what the issue was and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many tips but the only one that works is this one. Update the Maven configuration. Right-click on pom.xml, Run as -> Maven build (the 2nd one). Enter "clean package" in the Goals fields. Check the Skip Tests box. Then Run, it will properly download all the jars and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above solutions except manually installing jar in my repository.

By deleting the _remote_repositories file in the same directory as the "missing jar file" and doing maven update I got it to work.

This is the same end result as manually installing, I presume.

Answer (score 0):

My problem: I forgot to import a newly added project (added by my co-worker) into my eclipse workspace.

File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects, find it in the dir-tree, check the single non-ghosted one which is not already added.

Details: My co-worker had added a new project which was a git submodule. Existing projects referred to it in their pom.xml. I had already done "git submodule init" and "git submodule update". mvn built fine from the command-line but I kept getting this "Missing artifact" error in eclipse pointing at the top of my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me.

I had to delete all my maven local repository. Right click Project -> Maven -> Update Project. And FIXED!!

Answer (score 0):

When I copied from maven repository, there was 4th row called `<type>`.
When I removed this `<type>`, it solved my error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to just delete the `.m2` directory and run the build again.

**Note:** This will trigger the download of all the artifacts again, so I don't recommend doing it on slow or metered connections.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo eclipse
```

The issue for me was related to @maximilianus's question - in that eclipse was unable to locate the artifacts on my machine.

Turns out all I had to do was run ubuntu as super user, and eclipse could access the /root/.m2/ directory

*(Not sure this is good practice, but it solved a problem I've spent hours on)*

**Edit:** This is not definitely good practice, instead I setup my environment all over again, as a normal user rather than root, and it worked fine! (Learning Linux)