# Maven Dependency missing artifact

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am currently working on a Java project using Maven. In my `pom.xml` I am getting this error.

> `Missing artifact com.bea.xml:jsr173-ri:jar:1.0`

I have added this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.bea.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr173-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to my `pom.xml`. But still the error is same.

Am I missing adding repository for `jsr173-ri` dependency? I am also not getting repository to add in my `pom.xml`.

Can someone suggest me repository code for `jsr173-ri` to add in my `pom.xml`?

Comment: Maybe you will find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place

Comment: I'm wondering where this dependency is coming from to be honest. Perhaps you can exclude it because it is only for runtime purposes and is provided by the enterprise container?

Comment: Actually earlier this project was not configured for maven. But now I am working to migrate it to maven and I am writng pom.xml for same. So can i exclude this dependency from Maven dependency from Maven Build Path? Because I am almost done and I don't know from where it is ruining my whole work.

Comment: My maven repository also has this jar missing. It's strange. Maybe it was not installed/published properly.

Comment: @Mawia Have you found any solution for same?

Comment: @arun Well, if the jar itself is not available from maven repository, all you can do is install it in your local repository.

Comment: @Mawia yes, may be that is the only solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`com.bea.xml` is not available in [public repositories](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bea.xml/jsr173-ri)(Download size is zero). Therefore you need to download the JAR file and manually install it in to your local repo.

Some useful links: [Manually install dependency](http://blog.lakmali.com/2011/12/manually-install-maven-dependency.html)

Comment: Location to download `com.bea.xml` 1.0 jar : com.bea.xml `http://www.mmbase.org/maven2/com/bea/xml/jsr173-ri/1.0/jsr173-ri-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Add that missing jar in C:\Users\{your name}\.m2\repository\{dep jar folder}\{version-RELEASE}\{missing jar}

Step2: In Eclipse, right click on pom.xml -> go to Maven ->Add Dependency
Step3: Look for jar name in Enter groupId, artifactId
Step4: Select it in Search Results: and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is causing the problem? Haven't you missed anything else?

Here is the complete configuration (pom.xml) which you might need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bea.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr173-ri</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>JSR 173 - Streaming API for XML - Reference Implementation</name>
  <description>JSR 173 - Streaming API for XML - Reference Implementation</description>
  <url>http://dev2dev.bea.com/xml/stax.html</url>
  <distributionManagement>
    <downloadUrl>http://ftpna2.bea.com/pub/downloads/jsr173.jar</downloadUrl>
  </distributionManagement>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>BEA JSR 173 RI</name>
      <url>http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/bea/xml/jsr173-ri/1.0/jsr173-ri-1.0-license.txt</url>
      <distribution>manual</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <organization>
    <name>BEA</name>
    <url>http://www.bea.com</url>
  </organization>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr173</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I have a pom.xml in which I have added dependency of whole project. But at the first line of pom.xml it is showing missing artifact error. After that i added dependency code for jsr173 in my pom.xml but the error persist.

Comment: I have changed the `dependency` part of your desired library, as you might  already have noticed. Have checked that?

Comment: I have alreday tried that one. But error persists. I think problem is in repository. As I am getting from @Chandana answer, may be it is not available in public repository. I have to add jar file for same.

Comment: You don't have to add a file to your repository. You add a `dependency` and maven downloads it for you and puts it in the repository. In this case (_which must have given you another error_) delete that specific folder (which should contain your jar file) and rebuild your project.

Comment: I have decied to add jar file by using this code: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.bea.xml -DartifactId=jsr173-ri -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=E:\arun\jar\jsr173-ri-1.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true. I am not adding it explicitly. Isn't this right way?

Comment: What's the difference anyway? You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: But this jar is not avialbale in public repository :( How can maven download this jar?

Comment: I found it in the maven repository website. It sure can be downloaded. Search it for yourself. I strongly feel the problem lies in another place.

Answer (score 0):

dependency is correct....u don't have to change that.You can download the the jar from 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bea.xml/jsr173-ri/1.0 and put it on ur local repo.

Comment: Using that link, he can't ;) The jar isn't there.