# Is it possible to have a jar missing in Maven Central Repository?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

With reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099838/maven-dependency-missing-artifact),

> Is it possible that the jar file itself is missing from Maven Central
>   Repository?

check [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bea.xml/jsr173-ri/1.0)

You will find this
[image]

Download() (0 bytes)?

What is this?

Is this possible?

Why?

Could there be any problem while building that jar/dependency?

Comment: There is no jar file in central only pom.xml file.

Comment: Yeah It looks like the artifact (jar) isn't there.

Comment: It's probably a transitional entry that only exists to provide a transitive dependency on something else.

Comment: noupe, license issues O.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is going to be a problem: the build will fail because the dependency is missing.

As [answered by Chandana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099952/679982) from the post you referenced:

> you need to download the JAR file and manually install it in to your local repo.

e.g. I suppose that [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo/com/bea/xml/jsr173-ri/1.0/) is the jar in question, download it to some directory, create a file jsr173.pom in the same directory:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>com.bea.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr173-ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</project>
```

and install it to your local repo like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jsr173-ri-1.0.jar -DpomFile=jsr173.pom
```

and the build will pass. The file name and pomFile name will be regenerated by maven according to the data from the jsr173.pom file.

> Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible that the JAR file is missing from the repo. It can be because it is a parent pom, but if it is pom referencing a JAR file then that dependency effectively becomes unusable meaning that you have to solve it with the above procedure to use it.

> Why?

License issues, it is a copyright reference implementation, see [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/beehive/trunk/LICENSE.jsr173-api). It looks like this is a relativley common situation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository).