# Missing artifact error while adding a depentency in pom

Tags: java, maven

Am trying to add a dependency sauce-connect-plugin in to pom.xml file

```
<groupId>com.saucelabs.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>sauce-connect-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

But building the pom file am getting

```
 Missing artifact com.saucelabs:sauce-connect:jar:3.1.32
```

Also i mentioned the repository

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>saucelabs-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

in this url `http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/saucelabs/sauce-connect/3.1.32/` 
`sauce-connect:jar:3.1.32` is present
Then why `Missing artifact error` is showing??
What wrong with me.

When i directly add following in tho the pom file and added the repository am getting the same error

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce-connect</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.32</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried force update maven project?

Comment: the latest version of the com.saucelabs.maven.plugin:sauce-connect-plugin that I can see in the repository that you give is 2.1.13. What happens when you try that version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used mismatched versions:

sauce-connect-plugin presents in:
`http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/saucelabs/sauce-connect-plugin/`
which have only versions of `1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13 and 1.0.14`.
But you have tried to download `2.1.18`

What you mentioned with the URL `http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/saucelabs/sauce-connect/3.1.32/` will not represent for `sauce-connect-plugin`. It will represent for only `sauce-connect`

So you should try with following dependency:

```
<dependency>  
        <groupId>com.saucelabs.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sauce-connect-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.11</version><!-- 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13 or 1.0.14 -->
 </dependency>
```

If you need exactly the version of `2.1.18`, then you need to upload the artifact in the location `http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com` and try.

Comment: But when i add 2.1.16 as depentency am getting Missing artifact com.saucelabs.maven.plugin:sauce-connect:jar:2.1.14

Comment: you should try with the existing version

Comment: the existing version is 32 <dependency>
<groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
<artifactId>sauce-connect</artifactId>
<version>3.1.32</version>
</dependency> and facing the same issue :-(

Comment: Please check the connectivity for the URL through which tool you are trying to connect. Sometimes that also may be the reason.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6112344/2445298 (in eclipse) if you have issue still.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find someone who is also using this, try to compare your pom https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/blob/master/sauce-connect-plugin/pom.xml

Comment: i tired this one..but getting  
Missing artifact com.saucelabs.maven.plugin:sauce-connect:jar:2.1.32 error