# How to fix Malformed POM: Unrecognised tag: 'groupId'?

Tags: java, cassandra, maven-2, pom.xml, cql

I have a school project where i'am going to change the CQL (Caasandra Query Language), after doing that I need to create my specific Cassandra Java Driver, the problem that i couldn't run the source code of the driver on Eclipse i tried many things and i search in the internet but nothing work every time I have those kind of problem:

```
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging bundle from ClassRealm[project>com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Malformed POM I:\_Cassandra\java-driver-2.1\driver-core\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'groupId' (position: START_TAG seen ...<dependencies>\n  <groupId>... @36:12)  @ I:\_Cassandra\java-driver-2.1\driver-core\pom.xml, line 36, column 12
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
```

Answer (score 5):

The error:

> `pom.xml`: Unrecognised tag: '`groupId`'

means that you've malformed POM file (`pom.xml`) in line 36, column 12. In other words your placed `groupId` tag in the wrong place.

Since you  didn't posted your [Project Object Model](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) file, we can still see this part: `<dependencies>\n  <groupId>` which is incorrect. If you didn't change anything, you probably running old syntax of POM file under newer Maven.

To fix it, edit your `pom.xml` and correct the syntax. So under `dependencies` tag you should have `dependency` tags instead, then you can place your `groupId` tag, for example:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After correction re-run your Maven command (e.g. `mvn compile`/`mvn test`).

See also: [Maven2: Missing artifact but jars are in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6111408/55075)

Comment: I also received same error , this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place can help future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

```
   <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId> ----- </groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> (check your plugin ) 
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass> ------ </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

this will work ! replace ----- ;)
```