# Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE

Tags: maven, parent-pom

I am getting the following error in POM.xml for spring boot dependency.

> Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE

I tried all the solutions given in the following link but nothing solved my problem:
[Maven2: Missing artifact but jars are in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're getting this error because there is no jar artifact for spring-boot-starter-parent in maven central, since spring-boot-starter-parent uses pom packaging. The reason for that is because it's intended to be used as a parent pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Alternatively, you can just import the managed dependencies if that is what you intended to do:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You can read more about importing dependencies in the [Importing Dependencies section of the Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) article.

Comment: As for now, you should use spring-boot-dependencies:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent