# @SpringBootApplication not recognized when using spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.9.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot

from SPRING STS I've created a fresh spring boot project  starter , I've added "WEB" feature, and then finished creating the project

for some reason the import

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

is not recognized (I get -" The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved")

and thus the @SpringBootApplication annotation  is also unrecognized

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Newtest1sdfsdfApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Newtest1sdfsdfApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I'm using the project that was automatically created

if i change the project version of spring-boot-starter-parent (in pom.xml)
from 1.5.9 to 1.5.8 - all is well again. setting back to 1.5.9 shows the error

meaning changing from :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Any ideas what's the issue here?

Comment: Try out the suggestions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place) SO post. I could not find any issues with the mentioned version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up :

1. deleting two **sub-folders** from inside the **.m2** folder 
   The sub-folders were :  **org** and **com**
2. and then -> from eclipse/STS :  Right-click the Project name -> MAVEN -> UPDATE PROJECT