# Missing artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3 build successful still error

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, dependencies, maven-plugin

Edit>> Declaimer : This is not repeated question..

Hi Guys i am new to maven and i am trying to make an application which interact with oracle database but getting "Missing artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3" error. I have tried

**Step1:**

**mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile={locationInMyLappy}ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar -DgeneratePom=true**

**Step2:**

and in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

After then i am getting build successful in cmd

[image]

**Step3:**

besides this i have also made changes in windows>preference>maven>**installation** and **usersettings**..

I have already wasted 3 days in this only. Please help to resolve this. Please let me know if you want any other information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven2: Missing artifact but jars are in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place)

Comment: no duplicates here...in C:\Users\Hp\.m2\repository\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.3 and no downloaded jars here.....

Comment: Did you tried what was mentioned in same post. And it says **possible** duplicate, not exact duplicate. That is for your reference.

Comment: was trying the same post since 2 days but not able to resolve. in that post build is successful and i am not moving after that...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If your build is successful, then you don't have the error anymore. So what is the problem?

Comment: in cmd i am getting build successful as you can see in that screenshot but still my odbc jars are not getting downloaded in maven dependency and i am getting the same error in pom.xml which i was getting in start i.e."Missing artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Step 1, you have loaded the JAR into your local repo with a **different** groupId to the one that you are using as the dependency in Step 2.  Look carefully at the `-DgroupId` parameter.

Comment: yesterday i did what you are trying to say  but it didnt worked and today it worked...thank you for reminding this again....its solved