# Maven missing artifacts but files are in place - Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am getting two errors in eclipse(2020-03) in my maven project as,

````
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Shavindi\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\javax.servlet.jsp-api\4.0.1\javax.servlet.jsp-api-4.0.1.jar' ```

Missing artifact javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:4.0.1  pom.xml /ContactManager line 47 Maven Dependency Problem
````

I have followed the answers in this question [Maven2: Missing artifact but jars are in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place) . But it didn't work.

My **javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:4.0.1** files are already in place as shown below.

[image]

The pom.xml file is also atttached.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.codejava.contact</groupId>
  <artifactId>ContactManager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>13</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>5.9.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Remove `javax.servlet.jsp-api` and try whether maven gives an error or not ?

Comment: Is this what you want for `jsp-api` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api/2.0 ? It seems like you are using the incorrect one.

Comment: Did you check the filesystem?  Eclipse is displaying its view of the project, which can get out of sync with the filesystem.

Comment: @AnishB. when removing javax.servlet.jsp-api  there are no errors

Comment: Is your project running ?

Comment: @AnishB. I have not yet written a program specifically. When running maven test. It shows no error.

Comment: Updated your pom.xml as well. Plz check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the unnecessary `javax.servlet.jsp-api` dependency from `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Also, do `Project -> Clean` to check whether the error still persists or not ? If yes, then `Right Click on project -> Maven -> Update Project -> Select update of snapshot` and also enable `Project -> Build automatically`.

Moreover, they have moved the artifact as well. If you write the code later, you can use the dependency below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Your pom.xml is not proper. So, I have updated your pom.xml as well.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.codejava.contact</groupId>
  <artifactId>ContactManager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>13</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your POM.xml has wrong version of `javax.servlet.jsp`. Try replacing it with the following which is the latest version.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If the issue doesn't get resolved after the changes have taken place, follow the steps mentioned below and see if it helps.

- Right click your Spring MVC project, choose Run As -> Maven install. Observe the output console to see the installation progress. After the installation is finished, you can continue to the next step
- Right click your Spring MVC project, choose Maven -> Update Project.
- Choose your project and click OK. Wait until update process is finished.
- The error still yet, then do Project->Clean and then be sure you have selected our project directory and then do the follow Project->Build.