# Unable to add maven dependency for Apache Commons-csv

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

Hi All i am trying to add Apache commons-csv version 1.8 dependency for my spring boot project but getting following error.
Dependency 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8' not found. Also i am using Java 14.For your reference here i am also pasting my pom.xml.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Dependency looks ok https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.8 so I suspect some proxy/cache misconfiguration

Comment: @rkosegi hey i am using intellij Idea.How can i configure proxy/cache in my IDE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6112344/6821936

Comment: @SudhanshuRaman try `mvn dependency:resolve -U` and show us full error

Comment: Try to build on plain command line first to remove possible issues related to your IDE first....

Comment: project->maven->reimport worked for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because was fixed by OP

Answer (score 9):

**For Intellij Idea:** go to Maven(on right side) and press "Reimport All Maven Project".

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project folder -> Maven -> Reload Project.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on project
- Project->maven->reimport

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just upgraded the version to `<version>1.10</version>` from `<version>1.8</version>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```