# Tools.jar is not in Android Studio classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, chromebook

I tried installing Android Studio on a Samsung Chromebook Series 3 with an ARM processor, but I'm stuck with the Java. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Downloaded and extracted Android Studio
Downloaded and extracted Java 1.7.0_21 JDK ARM
Completed the below commands except the javaws commands as they error-ed out doesn't exist

tar xzvf ~/Downloads/jdk-7u21-linux-arm.tar.gz sudo mv jdk1.7.0_21/ /usr/lib/jvm/ 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java 1 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac 1 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javaws 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config java 
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

I tried the `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21` command and it would still give me the error.

Comment: Also interest in finding this solution. Eclipse works in Ubuntu installed with Crouton on Samsung Chromebook Arm, but I unable to get the Android Plugin to work. I also am able to load Intellij Idea once in Arch Linux using Chroagh on Samsung Chromebook... however, stops working after the first time, and idea.log does show any errors. Have had not success with Android Studio either with Ubuntu or Arch Linux.

Comment: Did you try to copy Java jars into Android Studio lib folder?

Comment: See if you can find what javac its trying to run. maybe on / do this: find . -name javac

Comment: I hope this link will resolve your issues. [Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827165/console-maven-compile-error/19827879#19827879

Comment: I hope this link will resolve your issues. [Console maven compile error][1] or 
[Missing tools.jar in local repository breaks m2eclipse][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827165/console-maven-compile-error/19827879#19827879
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273792/missing-tools-jar-in-local-repository-breaks-m2eclipse/16140087#16140087

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your system configuration is 32bit or 64bit and according to that download respective JDK and provide its path in JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1):

No It's not in the studio. What you should do:

- Change your JRE to use the JRE found inside your JDK
- Add tools.jar that can be found in the JDK Libraries folder

That's it. It's a known issue, but they're working on it. But this is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, you can check:
1. check jdk is in your path 
2. from your command line, execute this command: java -version
and see what it shows
3. and execute this command: javac -version
If both command gives no error then try again otherwise fix those issue.btw, Do not forget to check your system configuration to make sure that it is 32bit or 64 bit