# Console maven compile error

Tags: java, spring, maven

i was macking one of the oficial guides of spring: http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

But when y reach the part where i have to compile with maven this is what happens:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-maven-initial 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gs-maven-i
nitial ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory c:\Java\WorkSpace\maven_beginer\src\m
ain\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ gs-maven-init
ial ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to c:\Java\WorkSpace\maven_beginer\target\classe
s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.692s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 06 23:51:21 ART 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/102M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
5.1:compile (default-compile) on project gs-maven-initial: Fatal error compiling
: tools.jar not found: C:\Java\jdk\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Comment: Check to see if you have that missing jar:  C:\Java\jdk\..\lib\tools.jar

Comment: it's missing, tha's normal?

Comment: No.  It seems your Java JDK set up is wrong.  Or your Maven project is looking in the wrong location (probably some default location instead of where that jar actually is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by

1. Add JAVA_HOME to System variable
2. or Copy you java folder to c:\ from c:\program files or c:\program files (x86)
3. or [Missing tools.jar in local repository breaks m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273792/missing-tools-jar-in-local-repository-breaks-m2eclipse/16140087#16140087)

Answer (score 10):

Goto Windows -> Preferences
Java -> Installed JREs

[image: v]

Change JRE to JDK