# Error in Android Studio installation

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

That showswhen i run studio.sh. I have searched it in web and on this site. I know there are already solved topics, but I tried them and it didn't worked.

Im using ElementaryOS (Linux).

I have already installed JDK and the /etc/environment file is edited already, so why it shows?

Comment: Its still not working....

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a JDK installed on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Link to source https://askubuntu.com/questions/122133/tools-jar-is-not-in-idea-classpath

Comment: "I have already installed JDK and the /etc/environment file is edited already" but thanks you tried to help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JAVA_HOME is either not set, or is pointing to JRE and not JDK.

1. Make sure you have JDK 7 or 8 in your system.
2. Add the JDK home path to the Environment Variable JAVA_HOME

I am not sure what you tried already, so you can try out these:

[tools.jar seems to be not in Android Studio classpath on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528652/tools-jar-seems-to-be-not-in-android-studio-classpath-on-windows-8)

[Android Studio 'tools.jar' file is not present in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474963/android-studio-tools-jar-file-is-not-present-in-classpath)

[Tools.jar is not in Android Studio classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952990/tools-jar-is-not-in-android-studio-classpath)

PS: It would be helpful if you could list down all that you tried out to fix this issue, since this particular issue already had multiple answers in various threads.

Comment: I have just tried that. In environement its set to jdk and when I write java -version in terminal it shows me: java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: See what you have in the JAVA_HOME variable. Also check if you have the tools.jar file in the JDK.

Comment: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/ I don't know if something is wrong, when java was installing it was set automatically