# Maven Build failure - MyEclipse

Tags: java, maven, build, myeclipse

when i tried to build my project i am getting this error below as:

```
    BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 45.435s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 13 17:25:47 GMT+05:30 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/76M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project DPCommons: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
C:\MyEclipseWorkspace\Workspace_MayMU24\DPCommons\src\com\afunds\lang\ResourceClassLoader.java:[13,15] sun.misc.Resource is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

and the project names will appear below.

How can i overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps to solve that problem :

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> I have a JRE from
>   the JDK location, my location looks like C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26
>
> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> Execution
>   Enviroments -> Select JavaSE-1.6 and select a compatible JRE which
>   should be the one set in the previous step.

Look at this link -

[Maven in Eclipse complains that "Unable to locate the Javac Compiler" whenever POM changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163021/how-to-resolve-this-maven-issue)

Comment: i have given before as you mentioned here. then i tried. pls check is there any another way..to clear this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a JDK version which has this problem as per [this discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/compile-compile-failure-on-sun-proprietary-implementation-API-usage-td115960.html). Upgrade and retry.

Answer (score 0):

By providing the below arguments in the pom.xml of my project solved the issue.

```
<compilerArguments>
<bootclasspath>${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</bootclasspath>
</compilerArguments>
```

But still unclear as to why this works?