# Missing tools-1.6.jar with Eclipse and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tools.jar

I am trying to get a project to run using Maven in Eclipse, but I am getting this error below. The `tools.jar` is in the JDK's `lib` folder, but `tools-1.6.jar` doesn't seem to exist on my computer. I am using the JDK 1.7 and my `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to that folder (as is my `eclipse.ini`) Anyone know where I can get this file or what I might be doing wrong?

The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library `C:\Users\sejohnson\.m2\repository\com\sun\tools\1.6\tools-1.6.jar`

Comment: your .pom? your .project and .classpath files?

Answer (score 16):

The tools-x.y.z.jar should be provided by your JDK.

Make sure that eclipse is run by JDK and not by JRE by adding -vm option in eclipse.ini.

For example:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\javaw
```

New line after `-vm` is crucial.

it should be right above

```
-vmargs
```

See also [Eclipse Maven Plugin Configuration Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317402/eclipse-maven-plugin-configuration-problem)

Answer (score 14):

I had exactly the same problem and end up adding the following dependency to the pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

This fixed the problem and made `tools.jar` available for QueryDSL plugin in my project. Hope this helps. Note, make sure that JDK version is used instead of JRE.

Edit: Recently noted that problem reappeared when I moved on new dev platform, in my case it was Ubuntu 12.10. The fix was to add `${JAVA_HOME}/bin` to the `$PATH`

Answer (score 5):

It could be that your eclipse is defaulting to your 32bit version of your jre. If you do everything right with JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin and your running a 32bit version of eclipse you'll end up using something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin.

once you fix your jdk issue
You will need to pass it on the end of a shortcut
 -vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin"

Or fix your JAVA_HOME

Other suggestions have been to make sure your eclipse is using the jdk not jre
http://gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx

You'll find other post if you search tools.jar or playn another project with this common maven dependency issue.

Comment: I just encountered this issue, and pointing Eclipse to the JDK instead of the JRE fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your pom.xml for dependencies around tools? A good source is mvnrepository.com, finally does your project compile outside of eclipse? Does `mvn clean compile` work in a dos box or shell? If it does maybe you just need to regenerate the eclipse project files with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` then refresh your project in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The `tools.jar` is not provided in any public repository (as I know). If your `pom.xml` references a file in your local repository you must install it by your own. The pom.xml you are using apparently expects that someone created/installed a tools-1.6.jar in an accecable Maven repository (e.g. to a company central maven repositiory manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)).

If that does not fit for you try to change the dependency like explained in the Maven [FAQs](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the stated above, which could mean different steps to diagnose the problem and ultimately providing a proper solution, I'd first check in a command line (meaning, outside Eclipse runtime). Doing a plain 'mvn clean install' from a command line would give you the following:

1. Certainty of whether you have the java executables correctly set (as they're the defaults used by all java apps, including of course eclipse,
2. Certainty that your maven version does resolve the tools*.jar requirement via JDK provisioning adequately

Using these two facts you can rule out problems at Java installation and Maven installation levels. Then you can move on to making Eclipse use the same settings as you can use (JAVA JDK HOME, MAVEN HOME) in a command line, as the other answers above explain with good detail (specifically [brimstedt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74343/brimstedt) and [josh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841759/josh)).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it turned out that one of the dependencies in my POM file was transitively adding the dependency to the jdk.tools jar which I didn't need (and was causing the problems with the Eclipse Maven plugin). My solution was to exclude it from the problematic dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.unimi.di</groupId>
  <artifactId>mg4j-big</artifactId>
  <version>${mg4j-big.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Try looking for the dependency that is transitively importing the jdk.tools jar and just exclude like I did above. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks... I think that is the proper solution!  Everything else are just workarounds or hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I had to manually add the tools.jar in eclipse:
Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Select jre -> Edit -> Add External JARs -> Find and select tools.jar -> Finish.
Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option if you are having this build problem. I had the same build problem and i tried all of the above suggestions and the problem was still there. Then i noticed that my system path had the following "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" as the first item.

I am not sure which program installed it. And when i checked the folder it only had some links ( short cuts). I removed this from the system path and the build error was resolved. Hope this helps someone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Echo @Gopal Ramakrishnan. I had same problem in the env path (windows OS). It has "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in which has java.exe, thus impacted the actual jdk path when starting eclipse. Simply remove that resolved the problem. I am pretty sure the "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" was quietly added by oracle "sql developer"...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that I had this dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

However **JAVA_HOME** was set on startup of Eclipse to a **JRE instead of a JDK**.

So the tools.jar in fact did not exist for this reason

Answer (score 0):

Manually remove artifact from maven :

1. Goto "Dependency Hierarchy" Tab of pom.xml
2. Filter jdk.tools eg: (jdk.tools:1.6 [system])
3. Right click on jdk.tools and click "Exclude Maven Artifact"

Error will be resolved.