# Spark-HBase - GCP template (1/3) - How to locally package the Hortonworks connector?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hbase, cloudera, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to test the Spark-HBase connector in the GCP context and tried to follow [1], which asks to locally package the connector [2] using Maven (I tried Maven 3.6.3) for Spark 2.4, and leads to following issue.

Error "branch-2.4":

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project shc-core: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]`

References

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc

[2] https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/branch-2.4

Comment: Try building with Java 8 for "branch-2.4"; https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/185

Comment: An option to resolve "branch-2.3" is add the missing dependency to the pom file  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15618633/11866133

Comment: To get the full debugging picture, re-try executing your commands with the  --verbosity flag https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud#suppressing_prompting_writing_to_the_terminal_and_logging

Comment: @Ismail: Thanks ! I could build the jar using Java 8. May I ask you how to correctly add it to the `Dependencies.scala` in the GCP template - I tried a few options without success so far. Thanks !

Comment: Can you share the options you tried?

Comment: Ok packaging done, but I get another issue when submitting the job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466253/spark-hbase-gcp-template-parsing-catalogue-error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments (thanks [@Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11866133/ismail) !), using Java 8 works to build the connector:

`sdk use java 8.0.275-zulu`

`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

One can then import the jar in `Dependencies.scala` of the [GCP template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc) as follows.

```
...
val shcCore = "com.hortonworks" % "shc-core" % "1.1.3-2.4-s_2.11" from "file:///<path_to_jar>/shc-core-1.1.3-2.4-s_2.11.jar"
...
// shcCore % (shcVersionPrefix + scalaBinaryVersion) excludeAll(
shcCore excludeAll(
...
```