# Howto start eclipse in JDK?

Tags: eclipse, java

I just installed a Maven plug-in into eclipse the first time. Now there is a message on eclipse startup, that i should start eclipse in JDK not jre to make Maven components run fine. There is a -vm argument which I used in the eclipse.ini:

```
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\
```

But the message is still there after restart.

I've tried the:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin
```

and also the:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin\java.exe
```

But nothing changed.

How do I start eclipse in JDK?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, first you have to install a JDK.

Comment: First thanks for answereing all. I read most of the information before. Now I tried to inject the arguement via a windows shortcut. This works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Windows, right click on your eclipse shortcut and select Properties, in the Shortcut tab you can change what's in the Target: box to specify the jdk.  I use

```
"C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-galileo-sr1 (3.5.1)\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\javaw.exe" -vmargs -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
```

For some reason I couldn't get it to use the jdk when I tried editing the eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify which JVM to launch Eclipse under in your `eclipse.ini` file.  There are detailed instructions for different operating systems [on the Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Answer (score 4):

Found how to add it to the INI, must add the parameter to the line below the -vm option, as below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many more options in the [Equinox Launcher page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher).

And you have an example of a complete [eclipse.ini with all options there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590).

---

> When `no -vm` is specified, the launcher looks for a virtual machine first in a jre directory in the root of eclipse and then on the search path. If java is found in either location, then we look for a jvm shared library (`jvm.dll` on window, `libjvm.so` on *nix platforms) relative to that java executable.
>
> If a jvm shared library is found we load it and use the JNI invocation api to start the vm.
>   If no jvm shared library is found, we exec the java launcher to start the vm in a new process.
>   `-vm` specified on command line or in `eclipse.ini`
>   Eclipse can be started with "`-vm <location>`" to indicate a virtual machine to use. There are several possibilities for the value of `<location>`:

- `java.exe/javaw.exe`: `<location>` is a path to a java launcher. We exec that java launcher to start the vm in a new process.
- `jvm.dll` or `libjvm.so`: `<location>` is a path to a jvm shared library. We attempt to load that library and use the JNI Invocation API to start the vm in the current process.
- `vmDesc.ee`: `<location>` is a path to a file ending in ".ee". This file is expected to describe the execution environment for a jvm. See the Execution Environment Descriptions page.
- directory: `<location>` is a directory. We look in that directory for:

  - (1) a `default.ee` file,
  - (2) a java launcher or
  - (3) the jvm shared library.
    If we find the jvm shared library, we use JNI invocation.
    If we find a launcher, we attempt to find a jvm library in known locations relative to the launcher.
    If we find one, we use JNI invocation. If no jvm library is found, we exec java in a new process.