# SRVE0200E error on WebSphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere

I've developed a Java dynamic web project correctly deployed on *Apache Tomcat*. Now I'm trying to deploy the *.war* file on *WebSphere Application Server 8.5*. The enterprise application is correctly created but when I try to reach my application with browser I get the following error:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [it.foo.simpleapp.SimpleApp]: Could not find required class - class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.foo.simpleapp.SimpleApp
```

The application is very simple: it should answer with a *text/html* content when a *GET* arrives.

I'm pretty sure that *.war* file is correct but I'm new to WebSphere deploying.

The servlet class is:

```java
@WebServlet("/")
public class SimpleApp extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public SimpleApp() {
      super();
   }

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.getWriter().print("<html><body><h1>SimpleApp servlet ready!</h1>");
      response.getWriter().print("</body></html>");
      response.setContentType("text/html");
   }

}
```

The *web.xml* file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SimpleApp</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably related to the absence of some libraries used by *Tomcat* into *WebSphere* environment; so I solved compiling the code with IBM Java libraries. The following steps solved my problem.

1. Install the WASdev plugin for Eclipse. It can be retrieved from this URL: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/V8.5/
2. In Eclipse, under "*Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments*", a new runtime environment should be added clicking on the "*Add...*" button.
3. Under the "*IBM*" folder choose the "*WebSphere Application Server v8.5*" runtime environment and check "*Create a new local server*". In the next window the "*Installation directory*" must be provided; for example: `{your_path}\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer` .

   If during these operations a message like "*Secure servers are only supported with IBM JRE 6.0 or above. Use the IBM JRE from the product installation image.*" is shown, you can [follow this tutorial](http://ishtiaque.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/secure-servers-are-only-supported-with-ibm-jre-6-0-or-above-error-in-eclipse-ide/) in order to change the `eclipse.ini` content. The lines:

   ```
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx512m
   ```

   must be replaced with the following lines:

   ```
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -vm
   {your_path}\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin\javaw.exe
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx512m
   ```
4. Now you can create a new "*Dynamic Web Project*" specifing the *WebSphere Application Server* as a *target runtime*.

The exported *WAR* file works fine as *Enterprise application*.

I hope this can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Following step 3 above may not resolve the message like:

> "Secure servers are only supported with IBM JRE 6.0 or above. Use the
>   IBM JRE from the product installation image."

Instead of changing `eclipse.ini` you may need to add JVM directly to `eclipse.exe` command line like

> {eclipse_install_path}/eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\javaw.exe" -vmargs -Xmx1024m
>   -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode

see more at [Howto start eclipse in JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917760/howto-start-eclipse-in-jdk)