# javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E - Maven webapp

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I am trying to deploy a single maven webapp on a Websphere Liberty Server.

My code (XCCQuery.java):

```
package TTAQuery;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@WebServlet(name="XCCQuery", urlPatterns={"/hello"})
public class XCCQuery extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String simpleParam = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("simpleParam");
      out.println("Hello World "+simpleParam);
          out.close();

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>XCCQuery</servlet-name>
    <display-name>XCCQuery</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>XCCQuery</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XCCQuery</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I try to access:
http://localhost:9087/XCCQueryServlet/rest/hello

but always get:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [XCCQuery]: Could not find required class - XCCQuery
```

Seems to be a deployment mistake for me.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SRVE0200E error on WebSphere Application Server 8.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784489/srve0200e-error-on-websphere-application-server-8-5)

Comment: The servlet class you specified in the web.xml is `TTA.XCCQuery` but your package declaratiion for class `XCCQuery` says `package TTAQuery` instead of `package TTA`.

Comment: @Kenney edited my post now, but it still does not work, #firstpost.

Comment: If your java file says `package TTAQuery; ... class XCCQuery {...` then the web.xml should say `<servlet-class>TTAQuery.XCCQuery</servlet-class>` - have you tried that?

Comment: @Kenney, it says:

Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [TTAQuery.XCCQuery]: Could not find required class - TTAQuery.XCCQuery

Comment: Is the deployment and/or server startup running without errors?