# Eclipse locks up PC on first launch

Tags: linux, eclipse

I've just downloaded Eclipse on elementary OS and attempted to launch it. After doing so, I saw the loading screen for a few seconds before it disappeared and left me with the desktop. Since then, my computer (an old Dell with 4GB of RAM and an Intel Core Duo) has been very unresponsive and the disk activity indicator is almost constantly lit up. I've been looking at the desktop for around 30 minutes now! How can I solve this problem and launch Eclipse?

EDIT: Running `eclipse -clean` from the command line produces the following error: `The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized. Will retry after the state location is initialized.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might review your installation steps.  If nothing is obviously wrong, check the following:

- check for any error logs
- check that you're using the proper Java version
- make sure that there's enough memory allocated for Eclipse (see the eclipse.ini file)
- as a last resort, try reinstalling it

See also the following guide for installing on Elementary OS:  [how to install](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/05/27/how-to-install-eclipse-ide-for-java-developers-on-elementary-os-0-2-luna-3264bit-linux-easy-guide/)

If that's not working submit more details of your specific problems.

NOTE: You may have to find the right Java and install it "by hand" rather than relying upon the distribution's package manager.  You can "point" Eclipse at the right Java by [editing the .ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917760/howto-start-eclipse-in-jdk).

Some related links are as follows:

- [a similar symptom related to multiple screens and/or corrupt workspace](http://configuration%20bundle%20was%20activated%20before%20the%20state%20location%20was%20initialized)
- [General trouble-shooting related to your issue and symptoms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207843/how-do-i-prevent-eclipse-from-hanging-on-startup/5504530#5504530)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it isn't an ideal solution but I installed an older version of Eclipse and that booted up within seconds.

Comment: Glad you got **something** working!   I updated the answer a bit in case anything helps you (or someone else).  Are you doing Java dev or other languages?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Yep - Java dev.