# Eclipse wont start xubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse

I am having problems getting Eclipse to start on my Xubuntu machine but I am not sure what has changed since the last time. I used Eclipse without any issues.

The console output is:

```
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have tried running Eclipse -clean but got the same result.

Can anyone help me sort this please?

EDIT1:

eclipse -debug -console -consoleLog returns this from the console:

```
Start VM: /usr/bin/java
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 82800f
-debug
-console
-consoleLog
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar 
Install location:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/geeky/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/geeky/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/config.ini loaded
Shared configuration location:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
Splash location:
    /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/home/geeky/Desktop/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 31
!SESSION 2014-08-19 09:55:33.765 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -debug -console -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.478
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.479
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:../../../home/geeky/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.479
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.479
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.482
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.483
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata_1.0.200.20111228-1245 [219] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.483
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 09:55:36.483
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
Starting application: 2720
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g! No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

EDIT 2: Offical Sun java 8 now installed, eclipse still doesnt run the output of console reads:

```
eclipse -debug -console -consoleLog
Start VM: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/java
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 25f000f
-debug
-console
-consoleLog
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Install location:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/geeky/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/geeky/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/config.ini loaded
Shared configuration location:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
Splash location:
    /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/home/geeky/Desktop/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 37
!SESSION 2014-08-19 10:46:11.409 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -debug -console -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.636
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.637
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:../../../home/geeky/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.637
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.637
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.641
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.642
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata_1.0.200.20111228-1245 [219] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.642
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata 2 0 2014-08-19 10:46:13.642
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
Starting application: 2235
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g! No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I am not sure why OPENJDK is still listed just before the crash when the log starts with Sun java 1.8?

EDIT3:  Following this guide http://akovid.blogspot.com/2012/08/installing-eclipse-juno-42-in-ubuntu.html I have installed the lastest eclipse and migrated my workspace across.  It seems to be working now
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Try `eclipse -debug -console -consoleLog`. Then Eclipse will print a lot of log messages in the terminal where you started it. There is also an error log in your workspace: Look for `.metadata/.log`. It might contain something useful.

Comment: Thanks.  The .metadata/.log file contains the same as the console output posted above.

Comment: What is "Apache Felix Gogo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your log:

1. Apache Felix Gogo
2. OpenJDK Runtime

My experience with OpenJDK is ... not good. I avoid it whenever I can. Download the official Java release from the Oracle web site, install it somewhere and [point Eclipse to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217731/34088).

The next thing is this odd "Apache Felix Gogo". This seems to be a OSGi implmentation. I don't have a clue why that would be there; Eclipse comes with its own OSGi container (Equinox).

My guess is that someone tried to replace as many Eclipse components with "pure" Open Source  ones and they failed to do it right (like giving useful error messages when something breaks).

Try to download Eclipse from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and avoid all and any "special" Eclipse versions. I've seen people at Redhat and Debian trying to package Eclipse. While it might work for them, this has never reliably worked for me.

Comment: So i have installed JDK 1.8.0_11 from sun but am now struggling to get Eclipse to take that javavm.  I have run eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/ but OPENJDK runtime is still listed

Comment: `-vm` expects the name of the Java executable to run.

Comment: can you give me an idea what that might be in linux format?  From the log above am I not using the sun java executable?

Comment: `-vm /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/java`. You can also edit the file `eclipse.ini` and put the path in there. But make sure you put the option name `-vm` in one line and the path in the next one and both have to be before `-vmargs`

Comment: perfect thanks.  I had edited the eclipse.ini but had stopped short at the jdk/bin directory.